# How to change the date format in WordPress contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, date, contact-form-7

I am using the wordpress contact form and its field date picker, its default is DD/MM/YYYY, but I want to change its format to MM/DD/YYYY.

Can any one tell me how to do it in contact form 7.

Regards

Comment: Do you want to change it into the mail?

Comment: I'm looking for this too. Every answer I've seen online does not work.

Comment: the format is set by the browser, set your browser to en_US locale and the date will be in the format mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

If above writen code is not working its means:
If a value is specified in a date field, the value must be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (e.g. `2013-04-08`) according to the HTML5 specification.

This is in most cases you don’t need to care about because browser’s date picker UI will set a value in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the display date format to `mm/dd/yy` in the front end of my form by using plugin [Custom Datepicker NMR](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-datepicker-nmr/) for Contact Form 7.

This allows you to use a new input field in your contact form called `[datepicker ]`

Install/activate the plugin and specify format date to show in the web browser like this:

```
[datepicker myFirstDatepicker id:myFirstDatepicker format:mm/dd/yy]
```

This plugin uses [jquery-ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste it in your function file and also you can modify the date format as per requirement.

```
 add_filter('avf_datepicker_dateformat', 'avf_change_datepicker_format');
    function avf_change_datepicker_format($date_format) {
        $date_format = 'mm / dd / yy';
        return $date_format;
    }
```

Comment: what is this filter `avf_datepicker_dateformat`? i think you meant some other filter