# How to change date US format in contact form7

Tags: php, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7, I tried to change US Date format it will not work any help me
I'm tried below the code

[date* destination-date-205 _format_date-number "D, d M y" placeholder "MM/DD/YY*"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your code into the question but here:

```
[date* _format_destination-date-205 "D, d M y"]
```

Front end:

```
[date destination--date-205]
```

Comment: [date* destination-date-205 _format_date-number "D, d M y" placeholder "MM/DD/YY*"] i'm tried like this it's not working

Comment: @SatheeshKumar, updated my answer. You really need to edit your question with the relevant shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980760/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-wordpress-contact-form-7/60466669#60466669) you could write:

```
[datepicker* destination-date-205 id:destination-date-205 format:mm/dd/yy]
```