# date format doesn't working in contact-form-7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on contact form-7, i want to change the format of the date but it doesn't working, Can anyone please help me for that ? here is my code of that

```
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Name : [your-name]
Email : [your-email]
Phone Number : [tel-8]
What dates would you like to Book? : [date-971 "d-M-Y"]
Subject : [your-subject]
Message : 
[your-message]
```

Answer (score 0):

if a value is specified in a date field, the value must be in YYYY-MM-DD format (e.g. 2013-04-08). When the value is inserted into mail template, the date format keeps by default.

To change the format in mail, you can use a variant of mail-tag notation

```
[_format_{field name} "{date format}"]
```

In your case the mail tag that formats the field value is `[_format_date-971 "d-M-Y"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you like to format the date in the web browser too (and not only in the email), have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980760/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-wordpress-contact-form-7/60466669#60466669).
Your form code could look like:

```
What dates would you like to Book? : [datepicker date-971 id:date-971 format:d-M-y]
```

Also check jquery-ui datepicker [date format](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) to see what date formats to use.