# change date format in contact 7 form

Tags: php, wordpress

Not able change date format in wordpress contact 7 form.
I have tried as below code contact 7 date picker in India location.In settings->general-> date format d/m/Y.still not working.how to to change the date format in placeholder and date format using shortcode

```
[date* date-501_format_date-501 "d/M/y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't change the format on the input field, that is managed by the browser and always converted in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

You can change the format of the date showing on the emails generated by the form, something like this in the email template should work for you:

```
[_format_date-501 "d/M/y"]
```

You can check CF7 doc [here](https://contactform7.com/date-field/).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this *date format is managed by browser* problem, mentioned in the answers here, could be to use jquery-ui datepicker in Contact Form 7, as detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980760/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-wordpress-contact-form-7/60466669#60466669). So, install [Custom Datepicker NMR](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-datepicker-nmr/) and use:

```
[datepicker* date-501 id:date-501 format:d/M/y]
```